# How to run futures in their own execution context and not on the Actor System dispatcher. [Scala|Akka]

Tags: scala, akka, future, akka-stream, executioncontext

How do we use `src/main/resources/application.conf` for the same where the `dedicated dispatcher` in our code would automatically lookup in `application.conf` for the dispatcher

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's two example configurations for execution contexts you can put in your `application.conf`:

```
background-scheduled-tasks-dispatcher {                                                
  type = Dispatcher                                                                    
  executor = "fork-join-executor"    
  fork-join-executor {
    parallelism-min = 2
    parallelism-factor = 2.0
    parallelism-max = 10
  }
  throughput = 1
}

blocking-io-ec {
  type = Dispatcher
  executor = "thread-pool-executor"
  thread-pool-executor {
    fixed-pool-size = 50
  }
  throughput = 1
}
```

Here's an example of how to access one of them inside your app:

```
val ec :ExecutionContext = actorSystem.dispatchers.lookup("blocking-io-ec")
```

You can prefix the line with `implicit val ec` or you can use it explicitly

```
someFuture.map(myFunc)(ec)
```